# Passport/ Border troubles

Tags: visas, uk, europe, passport-renewals, customs-and-immigration

In Early September I was an au pair in Italy, but because I'm American I can only stay in the Schengen Zone for 90 days. I decided to continue as a nanny in Manchester, UK until my 90 days were up. Essentially, I said “working” to the UK border, so they sent me back to the USA.

My passport now has an ‘X’ across the Manchester stamp. Will this affect me re-entering the EU (I go through immigration in Portugal, despite my final destination being Italy)? Or am I better off getting a new passport? I’m not sure if they share the same database, but I don’t want to run into any issues again.

Comment: Did you have authorization to work in Italy?  Will you have authorization to work there when you return?

Comment: Are American citizens allowed to au-pair visa-free in Italy, or would you face the same issue there if you returned and told the Italian immigration official your real intentions?

Comment: Americans can go Visa free to Italy on a tourist visa, which is why the Americans I met who also Au Pair said “visiting” if they were even asked anything at all. The first time I went I wasn’t asked anything. But when they see the UK stamp, I’m wondering if that’ll run me into trouble.

Comment: @brhans From https://www.aupairworld.com/en/au_pair_program/italy/au_pair/visa/non_eu, it seems that it may be allowed, though it isn't completely clear to me.

Comment: I'm suspicious of aupairworld.com. Their suggestion for doing au pair in Italy longer than 90 days is to sign up for a language course.